# how to access database without webservice?

Tags: iphone, database, web-services

I am developing an iphone application and need to access Oracle/SQL database that installed on a server, and I dont want to develop a web service to read/write data, is there any other way to access the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting to a remote DB directly from an iPhone/iPad App is a very bad idea. Imagine someone with a jailbroken iPhone and a simple packet sniffer.... It would be incredibly easy to compromise the security of your Database.

The best way to acomplish this is to wrap it in php via a web server on your remote Database server. You can then run a query on the DB with a simple http POST request and have the page return xml/json/whatever.

---

You could look through [CocoaMySQL-src](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cocoamysql/) for some other ideas though.  I think the project is dead/no longer active, but the code might still be useful.